# Select2 Script Not Rendering Correctly When View is Returned From Action Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2

I have an MVC4 application. My index page contains a set up JQuery UI tabs. Within each of the tabs I have content that I manipulate and update using Ajax action links. On one of my tabs I have a Select2 option box. When first visiting the tab this box renders correctly and the Scripts function as they are supposed to. However, when I click one of the AjaxActionLinks, when the partial view returns from the controller the option box defaults the the basic functionality (Select2 not enabled). I believe the issue might be caused by the script not being rendered on the returned view. Is there a way that I can re-render this script when the partial view is returned from the ActionResult?

My Index page contains the Select2.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/select2.css">
```

My Tab Contains the Select2.js as well as the script to load and format the option box:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/select2.js"></script>

<!--- Select2 Script -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { $("#e1").select2(); });
</script>
```

My Tab also contains the Ajax.ActionLink... The Div that is being replaced is the entire tab itself. I know that this is working correctly because I use the same logic on all my other tabs.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("My Text", "ControllerMethod", new { param = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divToReplace", })
```

My Controller Method Just Builds a List and Sends It Back to the View:

```
    public ActionResult ControllerMethod (int param)
    {
        Session.Add("paramID", param);
        IEnumerable<SymbolAndNameDTO> myList = client.GetMyList();
        ViewBag.myList = myList;

        return View(ViewBag);
    }
```

So can anyone tell me why the tab option box renders correctly when the tab is first pressed but not after I click the AjaxAction Link? I have tried moving the scripts to my Index page but I cant get the option box to render correctly. Any help would be appreciated... I can provide additional details if necessary.....

Comment: you need to initialize select2 again on element in the success callback of ajax link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referencing JQuery twice... Once on the index page and then again on the view that was rendered.. stupid stupid. Thanks.